# horizontal scroll apear in the page when I active delete button that is a dialog

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a tabel that has approved column with 3 condition that one of that condition is when the item is not approved the delete button is showing and delete button has confirmation which I made that by dialog component of vuetify.

> the problem is when the delete button is showing, horizontal scroll
>   apear in bottom of the tabel. how can fix that

```
<v-data-table
                    :items="allLists"
                    :headers="headers"
                    :search="search"
                    class="mx-3"
            >
                <template v-slot:item.approved="{ item }">
                    <v-container fluid>
                        <v-checkbox v-model="item.checked" id="checkbox"></v-checkbox>
                    </v-container>
                </template>

                <template v-slot:item.action="{ item }">
                    <v-row>
                        <v-btn
                                text
                                dark
                                rounded
                                color="success"
                                v-if="item.checked === true"
                        >
                            <v-img
                                    :src="require('../assets/success.svg')"
                                    v-if="item.checked === true"
                                    max-width="30px"
                            ></v-img>
                        </v-btn>[enter image description here][1]
                        <template
                                v-if="item.checked === false"
                        >
                            <v-row>
                                <v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="290">
                                    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                                        <v-row class="mx-3">
                                            <v-btn
                                                    color="error"
                                                    text
                                                    dark
                                                    rounded
                                                    v-on="on"
                                            >
                                                <v-img
                                                        :src="require('../assets/deletenew.svg')"
                                                        max-width="29px"
                                                ></v-img>
                                            </v-btn>
                                        </v-row>
                                    </template>
                                    <v-card>
                                        <v-card-title class="red headline white--text">Confirm Delete</v-card-title>
                                        <br>
                                        <v-card-title style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px" class="justify-center">
                                            Are You Sure?
                                        </v-card-title>
                                        <v-card-actions>
                                            <v-btn color="primary"
                                                   class="font-weight-bold"
                                                   text
                                                   @click="dialog = !dialog"
                                            >
                                                No
                                            </v-btn>
                                            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                                            <v-btn
                                                    color="primary"
                                                    class="font-weight-bold"
                                                    text
                                                    @click="dialog = !dialog"
                                                    v-on:click="del(item.pk)"
                                            >
                                                Yes
                                            </v-btn>
                                        </v-card-actions>
                                    </v-card>
                                </v-dialog>
                            </v-row>
                        </template>

                        <v-btn
                                text
                                dark
                                rounded
                                color="warning"
                                v-if="item.checked == null"
                        >
                            <v-img
                                    :src="require('../assets/warning.svg')"
                                    max-width="29px"
                            ></v-img>
                        </v-btn>
                    </v-row>
                </template>
            </v-data-table>
```

[image: my tabel when scroll apear at bottom of that]

Comment: You can add width property to column headers and fix the overflow

Answer (score 1):

You can hide horizontal scrollbar using `overflow` property.

```
.mx-3{
   overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

[Docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

Comment: @NaserAhadi It is almost impossible to debug without looking at your DOM structure. I would look at elements and their box model. If not, create a small reproducible jsfiddle.